# c++ YUYV 422 Horizontal and Vertical Flipping

Tags: c++, yuv

I have a uint8_t YUYV 422 (Interleaved) image array in memory and I want to be able to flip it both vertically and horizontally. I have successfully implemented a vertical flip but I'm having a problem with flipping both horizontally and vertically at the same time.

My code for the vertical flip, below, works perfectly.

```
int counter = 0;
int array_width = 2; // YUYV

for (int h = (m_Width * m_Height * array_width) - m_Width * array_width; h > 0; h -= m_Width * array_width)
{
    for (int w = 0; w < m_Width * array_width; w++)
    {
         flipped[counter] = buffer[h + w];
         counter++;
    }
}
```

However, the following vertical and horizontal flip code appears to work but there is a loss of definition. To better understand what I am referring to, please see my sample images.

```
int x = 0;
for (int n = m_Width * m_Height * 2 - 1; n >= 0; n -= 4)
{
    flipped[x] = buffer[n - 3]; // Y0
    flipped[x + 1] = buffer[n - 2]; // U
    flipped[x + 2] = buffer[n - 1]; // Y1
    flipped[x + 3] = buffer[n]; // V

    x += 4;
}
```

As you can see, I am moving the YUYV components and keeping them in the same order. I don't believe that I am dropping pixels so I don't understand why I am losing definition. To reiterate, I don't see this problem when flipping vertically (Using the first code snippet).

Here is the reference image, please note the stem of the lamp:

[image: refrence image]

This is the flipped image, the stem of the lamp has lost definition:

[image: flipped image]

Comment: Please post the images as images and not as links. Not many people will actually open the links to look at the images, so if you want people to look at the images and therefore have a better chance to help you, it's better if you post them directly as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to swap Y0 and Y1 in your loop.

```
int x = 0;
for (int n = m_Width * m_Height * 2 - 1; n >= 3; n -= 4)
{
    flipped[x] = buffer[n - 1]; // Y1->Y0
    flipped[x + 1] = buffer[n - 2]; // U
    flipped[x + 2] = buffer[n - 3]; // Y0->Y1
    flipped[x + 3] = buffer[n]; // V

    x += 4;
}
```

While I was at it, since you're accessing `n - 3` I changed the loop condition to be absolutely sure it was safe.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mark Changing the Y values fixed my problem. I appreciate all comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

`m_Width * m_Height * 2` is not a multiple of 4 (the number of data blocks in YUYV format. Try changing '2' into '4', an also `array_width`.

Comment: That condition is confusing. Since 2 pixels occupy 4 bytes, there are 2 bytes per pixel, thus `* 2` is correct.